# Calculate future revenue based on a log growth formula similar to exponential growth formula?

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, logarithm, sigmoid-curve

The exponential (not continuous) growth formula from high school is:

$$A(t)=A^{kt}$$

Where $A$ is the initial amount, $t$ is the number of time periods and $k$ is the shape or growth rate.

Looking through a high school textbook one can calculate $k$ with two points from an exponential function.

I'm currently working with a dataset that looks to have logarithmic growth as opposed to exponential growth. I wondered if there's a similar formula that I could use to predict future amount $A$?

Business context is app installs. For a history of cohorts (people who installed our app on a given day), cumulative revenue is almost logarithmic:

[image]

And with `log(x)`, days since install 'tenure':
[image]

After two of 3 weeks of install for a given cohort, let's say day 21, I will know how much cumulative revenue the cohort has so far. If I thought of this as an 'initial' amount similar to the exponential formula above, is there some equivalent log growth model?

I assume that each cohort will grow with a similar shape but that the actual amount will depend on the initial amount as of day 21.

At this point I have some parameters that are similar to the exponential formula:

- $A$: initial amount as off day 21
- $t$: Tenure or days that have passed since day 21, e.g. day 25 would be $t=4$

If our cumulative revenue was exponential in shape I could use historic data to find two points, calculate $k$ and then make predictions about future revenue as of day n by plugging in the values.

Is it possible to do something similar with a log growth formula? Can I somehow rearrange the exponential growth formula to make it work for a log growth formula? My goal is to predict future cumulative revenue as of day n for a new cohort of installs as of 21 days old.

Comment: Does it matter if logarithmic or exponential? Why not just use a spline and get all non-parametric about it? I would be more worried that users would assume they can extrapolate like crazy out of this model than anything else. In fear of stating the obvious what is wrong with $A(t) = e^{A + k \log(t-3)}$?

Comment: Hi @usεr11852 thanks for your feedback and suggestions. "In fear of stating the obvious.." Actually I'm intrigued by this equation. Is it an exponential equation? Would you mind breaking it down? Would one calculate $k$ by considering two points and substituting like in high school math? How to find $k$? Also, what is going on with $log(t-3)$? Hand holding much appreciated!

Comment: Could I just flip the exponential function horizontally to make it into a logarithmic shape?